# Installing packetfence

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, ubuntu

I asked in the Ubuntu area, but thought I would get a better answer here.

Was anyone able to install packetfence on Ubuntu 10? I tried a [tutorial](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/386610:install-packetfence-for-powerful-network-access-control), but didn't have any luck. Some of the services installed and are working apache with php, snort, pfdetect, and pfdhcplistener. I can even get info with `pfcmd node view all`, but for the life of me I can't get it to work with apache2. When I run `pfcmd service pf start` I also get an error `uninitialized value $_[7] in join at /usr/local/pf/lib/pf/class.pm line 170`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work on the PacketFence project

It's complicated because of the interaction between PacketFence and the system components (apache, snmptrapd, named, dhcpd). As soon as the configuration files are not located in the same locations (`/etc/httpd/` vs `/etc/apache2/`) we run into problems. It is not only a packaging issue, the code will have to be patched.

However, good timing for you, it's something we want to tackle soon. Here's a ticket where you can track our progress: http://www.packetfence.org/bugs/view.php?id=1067

There will also be pointers to what is working and what is not. Feel free to chip in and help.

Comment: Just saw your message, thanks for letting me know!